# How can I copy a Java map to scala map using foreach

Tags: scala

I wrote like this:

```
import java.util.{HashMap => JavaHashMap}
import collection.mutable.{HashMap => ScalaHashMap}

def toScalaMap[K, V](jMap: JavaHashMap[K, V]) = {
    val sMap = ScalaHashMap[K,V]();

    jMap.forEach(_ -> sMap.put(_._1, _._2))
    sMap
}
```

But scala tell me:

> > error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: ) => x$1.$minus$greater(sMap.put(((x$2) => x$2._1), ((x$3) => x$3.*2))))
> >            jMap.forEach(* -> sMap.put(_._1, _._2))

So I add type to _:

```
jMap.forEach((_: (K, V)) -> sMap.put(_._1, _._2))
```

But scala tell me:

> > error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2: ) => x$2.*1)
> >            jMap.forEach((*: (K, V)) -> sMap.put(_._1, _._2))
> >
> > error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3: ) => x$3.*2)
> >            jMap.forEach((*: (K, V)) -> sMap.put(_._1, _._2))

So what is the right way to use foreach of Java Map in Scala?

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html):

```
 import scala.collection.JavaConverters

 def toScalaMap[K, V](jMap: JavaHashMap[K, V]) = jMap.asScala
```

In case of Scala 2.11.x or before as they do not support SAM usage, so [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)'s argument is not applicable for Scala functions.

In case of Scala 2.12, it should be a two argument list, not a single one with tuple:

```
jMap.forEach((k: K, v: V) => sMap.put(k, v))
```

(One further note: In Scala the functions are using `=>`, not `->`.)